# Where is the phase information coded in Fourier Transform?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Take the usual Fourier transform of a function $f(t)$:

$$F(s)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) e^{-i2\pi st} dt$$

Naively, I think that $f(t)$ has to be tested "against" all frequencies $s$ and all phases (I mean, it's not only the "right" $s$ that matters, but also the right phase)...but where is the phase information coded? Or am I wrong in my interpretation of the FT?

Comment: Could you explain a bit better? It's not clear what exactly you're asking.

Comment: Thanks @CameronWilliams I've tried to make it clearer, discarding the irrelevant informations

Comment: Unfortunately, only now I realize that my question was wrong from the premises. I'd like to delete it but dunno if it's legit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is poorly defined enough that I hesitate to suggest that the following *may* be an answer:

There's no need to "code" information about phase-shifted complex exponentials separately, because that's contained in the information about the unshifted exponential. If $\phi$ is a real   constant then $$\int e^{-i(t+\phi)\xi}f(t)=e^{-i\phi\xi}\int e^{-it\xi}f(t).$$

**Edit:** As of a comment below, I think I have a better idea what the OP is actually asking. THe problem has been what we mean by "the phase information". Now he ask specifically why/where/how terms  like $\cos(n(t-\phi))$ were "discarded" in the transform of $\cos(t)$; evidently the "phase information" is the component of such terms.

**Note** I'm going to talk about Fourier series (for  $2\pi$-periodic functions)  instead of the Fourier transform, because the very notion of the Fourier *transform* of $\cos(t)$ is problematic.

The Fourier series for $\cos(t)$ is indeed $$\cos(t)=\cos(t).$$

Why is the coefficient of $\cos(t-\phi)$ zero? The question itself involves a misconception. Given two functions $f$ and $g$ there's really no such thing as the component of $g$ in $f$; in fact $f$ has coefficients with respect to an *orthonormal family of* functions. When we're doing Fourier series we talk about expansions in terms of $\cos(nt)$ and $\sin(nt)$, so there simply is no coeffcient of $\cos(t-\phi)$ in the expansion.

So if we wanted to concoct an answer to the question of where $\cos(t-\phi)$ was "discarded" in the expansion of $\cos(t)$, the answer would be that it was discarded when we *chose* to use $\cos(nt)$ and $\sin(nt)$ for Fourier series. If we used a different orthonormal basis then $\cos(t-\phi)$ might *not* have been "discarded".

Honest. For example, we *could* use expansions in terms of the functions $\cos(n(t+2))$ and $\sin(n(t+2))$. Writing $\cos(t)=\cos((t+2)-2)$ shows that $$\cos(t)=\cos(2)\cos(t+2)+\sin(2)\sin(t+2).$$So in this strange version of Fourier series the $\cos(t+2)$ is *not* "discarded"; the coefficient of $\cos(t+2)$ is $\cos(2)$.

To put it all another way: The notion of "With phase shifts or without phase shifts" is not intrinsic to a function, it applies to how we choose to *represent* a function. The function $\cos(t)$ *is* a sum of *phase-shifted* sines and cosines.

Comment: I am sorry that the question is not well defined. Anyway, are you saying that in the exponential I've written, $e^{-i2\pi st}$, the phase shift is _yet_ coded?

Comment: @LoScrondo I have no idea whether I'm saying that, because I don't know exactly what "the phase shift is yet coded" _means_. What I'm saying is what I said: There's no reason to worry about that phase shift.

Comment: Ok, I'm supposing there's something that I've misunderstood. To let me see where I am wrong, let me use the simplest example I could make: suppose that $f(t)=cos(t)$. In this case it is obvious that the FT consists in a cosinusoid with a phase shift = 0, so other phase shifts (different form $2k\pi$) are discarded. How this discarding happens?

Comment: @LoScrondo I think I finally figured out what you're asking. See edit...

Comment: Thank you @DavidCUllrich!!! In the last hours, when you (very kindly) reformulated your answer, I acknowledged how much wrong was my question. I wished to delete it, now, instead, I thank you for your effort and choose your answer as the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a single simple example will make things clearer. Let
 $\, f(t) := \cos(2 \pi a t + b) \exp(-c t^2). \,$ The transform
 $\, F(s) = \frac12(\exp( +i b - \pi^2 (s+a)^2 / c) + 
  \exp( -i b - \pi^2 (s-a)^2 / c)) \sqrt{\pi/c}. \,$
The frequency $\, a \,$ is also paired with $\, -a. \,$ Thus we are interested in the Fourier transform at these two values of $\, s. \,$
 $\, F(a)=\cos(b + i\, 2 \pi^2 a^2/c) \exp(-2 \pi^2 a^2/c) \sqrt{\pi/c},
  \, F(-a) = \overline{F(a)} \,$ is the complex conjugate. Notice that if we are
given the values of $\, a,c \,$ we can solve for $\, b \,$ the phase value using
either $\, F(a) \,$ or its conjugate $\, F(-a). \,$ The situation is similar in  general.